# Linker error only while archiving

Tags: iphone, ios, linker-errors, archive, ipa

When I build my project with iOS Device, there is no error. I can even run the project on simulator wit debug mode. But when I try to create an ipa using archive, this error comes up. [image]
I just added another device in the profile, downloaded the new profile and added it in organizer. And now it doesn't let me create an ipa. I tried downloading certificate again, restarting Xcode. But it did not work.

**EDIT**
When I remove the line which calls QuotedPrintable::decode() method, it works fine. How do I set path to quotedPrintable.h in the build settings?

Comment: Check keychain there are two certificates delete old one. and remove old one profile.

Comment: i have deleted the older one already

Comment: Often, Build Active Architecture Only to No.

Comment: ALSO https://stackoverflow.com/a/54081211/294884

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had given multiple paths in **Library Search Paths ** that confused xcode. Removing the unwanted, and wrong ones solved the problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you have different architecture-related settings for Debug and Release configurations (by default run on simulator uses Debug and Archive uses Release). Try to make all architecture-related settings you find (ones with armv%x%) be like for Debug and check what happens.